# How I can make physical exercise illustrations?

Tags: 3d, illustration, education, modeling, anatomy-for-artists

Like this:
[image: Illustration]

I think this created with a specific program, because I've seen this 3d model at 10+ different site.

I did research for 6 hours, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 1):

It's likely a 3D model adapted/posed using 3D modelling software such as Blender, or similar. There's a Blender Stack Exchange for specific Blender questions. Also there are lots of Blender tutorials on youtube.  You can find stock 3D models for purchase on various stock 3d model sites, such as cgtrader, or turbosquid. Do a search on one of these 3d stock sites for anatomical models, gym equipment, etc.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, I don't know *why* anyone would want an image that appears to be so prevalent *everywhere*. It doesn't help any brand stand out as unique if they simply use what everyone else is using.

I *don't know* if you are asking **how** to make these... or just wanted to **find** similar images for use.

Anyway...

30 seconds of reverse image searching found the royalty-free images and video clips available for purchase at https://www.shutterstock.com

[image]